# How to set row id from server after adding new row in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid does not set row id if new row is added using form editing, saved to served and server returns autogenerated row id.
Subsequent editing of added row causes error.

I tried free jqgrid from github using code below but problem presists.

To reproduce, open page below in browser, click plus button to add row and pess submit and then cancel
Id column is empty. Code containts:

```
           afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
               return [true, '', '100'];
```

which simulates server response returning remote id 100.
So Id column should contain vlaue 100 after adding.

I posted it also in github as free jqgrid issue but havent got any responses.
How to fix it so that rows can added using form editing ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                ],
                $grid = $("#list");

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Client", "Id"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name", align: "center", editable: true },
                    { name: "id" }
                ],
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                        savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                    if (savedRow.length > 0) {
                        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
                    }
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {
                        keys: true
                    });
                }
            })

.jqGrid('navGrid', {}, {},
{
}
})
;

        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you! It's a bug in jqGrid 4.7, see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L704):

```
idname = url === 'clientArray' ? $t.p.keyName : opers.id;
```

Free jqGrid are based on the jqGrid 4.7 so it have the same problem too. I posted  just now [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/49d0c7559efa526bd636233ba77a84ec7cf912fe), which changes the above line to the following

```
idname = url === "clientArray" && p.keyName !== false ? p.keyName : opers.id;
```

Now the problem should be solved.

Comment: This fixes issue for local data only. If remote json data is used, problem still persists.

Comment: @Andrus: My tests with remote saving of data and `reloadAfterSubmit: false` shows no problems. The value of `id` attribute of new added row will be correctly assigned to the value returned by `afterSubmit`. Do you verified the problem in the same way or you have some column which have `key: true`  column or the column with the name `id` in the grid? Modifying of the columns are not the feature of jqGrid (at least in all old versions). So you need just add the line `postdata.id = '100';` inside of `afterSubmit`. If the column is not editable, than you can use `setCell` to assign the value.

Comment: @Andrus: Absolutely another remark. If you use the current sources of free jqGrid then you can use `iColByName` parameter which is the map which gives column index in `colModel` by the value of `name` property. It can simplify some parts of the code.

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571905/how-to-change-value-of-id-column-in-form-editing