# How to change value of id column in form editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm looking for a way to change the value of id column using form editing.

I tried code below: selected row, clicked in form edit button and changed anda and id.
After pression submit button id column value is not changed in grid. How to change id column vaue also ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [ { name: 'name', id:'id'}
                ],
                $grid = $("#list");

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Client", "Id"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name",  editable: true },
                    { name: "id", editable: true }
                ],
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                        savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                    if (savedRow.length > 0) {
                        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
                    }
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {
                        keys: true
                    });
                }
            })

.jqGrid('navGrid', {}, {},
{
//           afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
//postdata.id='100';
//               return [true, '']; //, '100'];
// }
})
;

        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Oleg: I tried but problem persists. I described issues more detail in comments to your answer. In my application natural primary keys are are used and users like to change them in form and inline editing mulitple times. We discussed this in other answer years ago and you recommended to use surrogate ids but this is out of scope for this question. Currently after id is changed full screen refresh is required before row can edited again. I'm looking for a way to avoid this extra screen refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, but I think that the usage of

```
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
    postdata.id='100';
    return [true, '', '100'];
}
```

should work. I think that you can modify **any** even non-editable column in the way, but only in case of adding new row.

The only exception could be the `id` column because of [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L892) (or [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L778) of jqGrid 4.7).

To be sure that one don't have the case I [modified](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ce6a225bacad436c98afa79b4cfdd502993f7d09) the code of free jqGrid once more. You should try with the latest sources of free jqGrid

Comment: Question was about updating **existing row id** using form editing. I re-tested code in question which uses jqgrid from github master but problem persists: clicking in edit button, changing id column and pressing submit button still shows old id value in jqgrid column.

Comment: I added `postdata.id='changed id in form'` to form edit afterSubmit method. In this case grid shows new id but attempt to edit row again still posts old id to server. How to force jqgrid to post new  id to server after id is changed in form and row is edited again after that? If id is changed using inline editing, changed row with new id can edited without issues.

Comment: @Andrus: I'm sure that there are **no `editable: true`** in `id` column in the text of your column during I wrote the answer. You can't just change the question because my old answer will be not more full correct! If you have editable column with `name "id"` and no `key: true` then you have name conflicts and you can to change the name of rowid which will be sent to the server:  `prmNames: { id: "newIdName" }`

Comment: You can click all actions revision in my name. There are no revisions on this question. Also I dont remember that I have changed this. There are similar testcases in other questions. In other questons id is always read only but for this question I specially make id editable.  So it looks like I havent changed this question in any way. Maybe I should create more real testcase but I dont know how to provide remote controllers for it.

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, it seems that I'm wrong and I confused the code with other codes which you posted because I answered on the questions parallel. Nevertheless do you tried to rename rowid send to the server to another name? The default name for the **old** rowid (which is `"_empty"` in case of Add form) is `"id"` if you need to use the name as the column name then you have to use something like `prmNames: { id: "oldRowId" }`. In the case the rowid will be sent under the name `"oldRowId"` and `"id"` will be from the editable `"id"` column.

Comment: Adding `prmNames: {id: "_rowid"},` and `mydata = [{ _rowid: 'id', name: 'name', id:'id'}]` to sample code fixes the issue in question. However if remote json data is used, old id is still posted to server edit method if this row is edited again. `postdata.id='100'` refreshes id column only. I tried to add `postdata._rowid='100'` but old rowid is still posted to server edit controller after form editing. If only inline editing is used, changed id is posted correctly as _rowid

Comment: jqgrid is populated from remote json data in form `{"total":2,"page":1,"rows":[{"id":"oldid","cell":[null,"oldid","test... `   It looks like postdata changes only cell part of data.  `oldid` is posted again even if id value is changed using `postdata.id='newid'` in edit method `afterSubmit` . Maybe id value from data is used as <tr> element id. How to change jqgrid row id ? Maybe `afterComplete` method can used.

Comment: @Andrus:  One should have full scenario with the test data. Your question was about ignoring new id returned from `afterSubmit`. It means that the question about Add operation in Edit form.. Moreover it means indirect that you use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` option additionally.  If the data will be realoaded (by default) than nothing is required to do. What scenario you mean now? Is it Edit operation (instead of Add previously) of form editing? If one have clear demo example (in jsfiddle for example) and the test case then one can easy understand the problem and fix something if required.

Comment: @Andrus: See the demo as an example of jqGrid demo which use remote data.

Comment: I posted question containing full testcase in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588844/how-to-set-row-id-value-after-form-editing-in-free-jqgrid

Comment: I researched the issue using testcase in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588844/how-to-set-row-id-value-after-form-editing-in-free-jqgrid  Yesterdays github jquery.jqgrid.src.js source code line 10026  contains `$self.jqGrid("setRowData", postdata[idname], postdata);` but setRowData does not set id for remote json data. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus: The line is not new. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L796) for example. If you want to change the `id` attribute of the row you have to set it explicitly. I remind me that we have already discussion about the subject. I think that one should make design of database to that no ids will be changes during **editing**, only during creating new items. It guarantee no id conflicts. Nevertheless I will post later my answer with the idea of an possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you. I updated testcase in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588844/how-to-set-row-id-value-after-form-editing-in-free-jqgrid and added proposed workaround. Problem persists. New id is passed to attr() in afterComplete but old id is still passed to server on second edit.