# How to set row id value after form editing in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Table has primary key with 3 columns (Grupp,Kuu,Toode) and server returns Id created from those columns.

After primary key column is changed in form editing, server sends new row id back.

Free jqgrid does not set this row id as changed row id. Server returns new id.

I tried to change id in code below in editfor afterSubmit method by using

```
function EditAddForm_AfterSubmit(response, postdata) {
  var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
  return [true, '', json.Id];
  }
```

but old id is still passed to server if row is edited again.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open page below in Chrome
2. Select row by clicking in it
3. Use toolbar edit button to open form editor
4. Change field Kuu value
5. Press submit button. Changed value appers in Kuu column in jqgrid
6. Double click in row to start row editing
7. Press enter. Error message from server appers since wrong (old) primary key
   is passed to server.

code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <base href="http://example.com/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="http://example.com/Content/Css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://example.com/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <title>
Old primary key value is passed if primary key is changed
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        var BASE_URL = 'http://example.com/',
            Message = {
                selectRows: "Select",
                sendingQuery: "Send"
                };
    </script>

<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/jqgrid-4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/erp.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/AfterGridInit.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/TinyMCE/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/Scripts/TinyMCE/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var 
        $grid,
        lastSelectedRow,
        autoedit = false,

          jqXHRFromOnSuccess,
          idsOfSelectedRows,
          myColumnsState,
          isColState,
          myColumnStateName;

    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
        mtype: 'POST',

        iconSet: "fontAwesome" ,
        navOptions: {
            position: "center"},

        autoResizing: { compact: true,widthOfVisiblePartOfSortIcon: 13 },
        toppager: true,
        viewrecords: false,
        onSelectRow: grid_onSelectRow,
        onSelectAll: grid_onSelectAll,

        sortable: function (permutation) {
            saveWindowState();
        },
        multiselect: true,
        ajaxRowOptions: { async: true },
        scrollrows: true,
        prmNames: {  
            id: "_rowid", page: "_page", rows: "_rows", oper: "_oper", sort: "_sidx", order: "_sord",
            nd: "_nd"
        },
        loadui: 'block',



          cmTemplate: { fixed: true, autoResizable: true },
        autoencode: true,
        gridview: true,

        serializeGridData: function (postData) {

            var myPostData = $.extend({}, postData);
            myPostData._filters = myPostData.filters;
            delete myPostData._oper;
            delete myPostData.filters;
            delete myPostData.searchField;
            delete myPostData.searchString;
            delete myPostData.searchOper;
            return myPostData;
        },

        shrinkToFit: false

    });

    $.extend(true,$.jgrid.edit, {
        beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid) {
            showModeless('Saving');
            return [true, ""];
        },

        closeAfterAdd: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var editParams =  {
      // code added according to proposed answer
      afterComplete: function (jqXhr, postdata, $form, formOper) {
            if (formOper !== "add") {
                var json = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
                $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(postdata._rowid)).attr(json.Id);
            }
        },

        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
            return EditAddForm_AfterSubmit(response, postdata);
        },

      url: 'http://example.com/Grid/Edit?_entity=Grnait',
      closeAfterEdit: true
      };

    function selectedRowsAction(action) {
    }

    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        var urlFilters,
                namedParameters = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'),
                parameters = {},
                nameAndValue,
                i,
                cm= [{"hidden":false,"label":"Tegevus","name":"_actions","search":false,"width":72
,"sortable":false,"formatter":"actions","viewable":false,"formatoptions":{"editbutton":true,"onSuccess":function (jqXHR) { jqXHRFromOnSuccess=jqXHR;return true;}
,"delbutton":true,"delOptions":{"url":"http://localhost:52216/admin/Grid/Delete?_entity=Grnait","afterComplete":function (response, postdata, formid) { 
summarefresh($grid);
$grid[0].focus(); 
}
}}},{"label":"Objekt","name":"Grupp","index":"Grupp","edittype":"select","editoptions":{"formatter":"select","value":":;1:1;11:11;14:14;2:2;21:21;22:22;23:23;251:251;30:30;31:31;40:40;41:41","class":"ui-widget-content jqgrid-inlineedit-element","style":"width:100%;max-width:210px;height:130%","dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {
updateSelectValue(this, 'Grupp');
dataChanged(this);
}
},{"type":"keydown","fn":function(e) {
if(!enter(e)) return;
updateSelectValue(this, 'Grupp');
dataChanged(this);
}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}]},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"editable":true,"width":70,"hidden":false},{"label":"Artikkel","name":"Toode","index":"Toode","edittype":"custom","editoptions":{"maxlength":20,"size":20,"lookup":"ToodeL","custom_element":function(value, options) {
return combobox_element(value, options,'38','Toode','Grnait','YToode')}
,"custom_value":combobox_value
},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"editable":true,"width":60,"hidden":false},{"label":"Artikli nimi","name":"Toode0_nimetus","index":"Toode0_nimetus","edittype":"custom","editoptions":{"maxlength":0,"size":0,"lookup":"ToodeL","custom_element":function(value, options) {
return combobox_element(value, options,'78','Toode0_nimetus','Grnait','ArtikliNimi%c3%9c%c3%bcriarvestusel')}
,"custom_value":combobox_value
},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"editable":true,"width":100,"hidden":false},{"label":"Algnäit","name":"Anait","index":"Anait","align":"right","searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"]},"editoptions":{"maxlength":13,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"style":"text-align:right","readonly":null,"class":"jqgrid-inlineedit-element ","disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":63,"classes":null,"hidden":false},{"label":"Kuu","name":"Kuu","index":"Kuu","editoptions":{"maxlength":6,"size":6,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"readonly":null,"class":"jqgrid-inlineedit-element ","disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":43,"classes":null,"hidden":false,"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"stype":"text"},{"label":"Lõppnäit","name":"Lnait","index":"Lnait","align":"right","searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"]},"editoptions":{"maxlength":13,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"style":"text-align:right","readonly":null,"class":"jqgrid-inlineedit-element ","disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":74,"classes":null,"hidden":false},{"label":"Kogus","name":"Kogus","index":"Kogus","align":"right","searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"]},"editoptions":{"maxlength":13,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"style":"text-align:right","readonly":null,"class":"jqgrid-inlineedit-element ","disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":71,"classes":null,"hidden":false},{"label":"Koguse jagamine","name":"Klassif1_nimetus","index":"Klassif1_nimetus","edittype":"select","editoptions":{"formatter":"select","value":":;R:Arvestuslik pind ;E:Elanike arvu järgi ;K:Korterite järgi ;:Kõigile sama ;V:Köetav pind ;P:Pindala järgi ","class":"ui-widget-content jqgrid-inlineedit-element","style":"width:100%;max-width:327px;height:130%","dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {
updateSelectValue(this, 'Kogusx');
dataChanged(this);
}
},{"type":"keydown","fn":function(e) {
if(!enter(e)) return;
updateSelectValue(this, 'Kogusx');
dataChanged(this);
}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}]},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"editable":true,"width":109,"hidden":false},{"label":null,"name":"Kogusx","index":"Kogusx","editoptions":{"maxlength":1,"size":1,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"readonly":null,"class":"jqgrid-inlineedit-element ","disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":0,"classes":null,"hidden":true,"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"stype":"text"}],
                //colModel,
                //sortName,
                emptyMsgDiv = $('<div style="display:none"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ei leia</div>');


        $grid = $("#grid");
        myColumnStateName = "Grnait.0.colState"; // 'Grnait.colState';
        myColumnsState = restoreColumnState(cm, myColumnStateName);
        isColState = typeof (myColumnsState) !== 'undefined' && myColumnsState !== null;
        idsOfSelectedRows = isColState && typeof (myColumnsState.selectedRows) !== "undefined" ?
                                    myColumnsState.selectedRows : [];
        urlFilters = isColState ? myColumnsState.filters : {};

        $grid.jqGrid({
            postData: { filters: urlFilters


                            },
            datatype: "json",

            rowNum: isColState ? myColumnsState.rowNum : 50,
            url: 'http://example.com/Grid/GetData?_entity=Grnait',
            colModel: cm,
                editurl: 'http://example.com/Grid/Edit?_entity=Grnait',


            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                var $this = $(this), rows = this.rows,
                  startId = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
                  startRow, endRow, iStart, iEnd, i, rowidIndex,
                  colName = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
               $self = $(this),
               savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow"),
               cmd = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');


                $("body").children("ul.ui-jqgrid-showHideColumnMenu").menu("destroy").remove();


                if (cmd[colName].name === 'cb' ) {
                    return true;
                }


                if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
                    //                if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== "undefined" && lastSelectedRow !== rowid) {
                    cancelEditing($grid);
                }

                if (!autoedit || ClickedInActionButton(e)) {
                    resetSelection();
                    return true;
                }


                if (lastSelectedRow !== rowid) {
                    jqGrid_editRow(rowid, afterGridSaveFunc, colName );

                    // PutFocus(e.target);
                }
                                PutFocus(e.target);
                return true;
            },




            ondblClickRow: function(rowId,iRow,iCol,e) {

                if (autoedit) {
                    return;
                }

                if (isInlineEdit()) {
                    return;
                }
                openDetail(rowId);
                PutFocus(e.target);
            },
            formDeleting: formDeletingTemplate
        });


        emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter($grid.parent());

        $grid.jqGrid('bindKeys', {
            scrollingRows: true,
            onEnter: openDetail
        }  );


        $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", {
            edit: true
        },
        editParams,
       {
       },

    { 
    },
         searchParams
    ,
       {            }
                );

        var reloadWithNewFilterTemplate = function () {
            $grid.trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true, page: 1}]);
        };
        GridCommon(false, 'Grnait',-1 );

    }); 

    function openDetail(rowId) {
        jqGrid_editRow(rowId, afterGridSaveFunc,false);
    }

    function addDocument() {
    }

    function onInlineEdit(rowId) {
        var savedRow = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
        if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowId) {
            // if (rowId && rowId !== lastSelectedRow) {
                cancelEditing($grid);
            lastSelectedRow = rowId;
        }
    }

    function PutFocus(target) {
        $("input, select",target).select();
            }

    function afterGridSaveFunc(rowId, response) {
            aftersavefunc(rowId, response);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EditAddForm_AfterSubmit(response, postdata) {
        clearModeless();
        if (response.responseText.charAt(0) === '{') {
            var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    postdata['Grupp'] = json.PrimaryKeyValues[0];
                    postdata['Kuu'] = json.PrimaryKeyValues[1];
                    postdata['Toode'] = json.PrimaryKeyValues[2];
            return [true, '', json.Id];
        }
        alert( decodeErrorMessage(response.responseText, '', ''));
        return [false, decodeErrorMessage(response.responseText, '', ''), null];
    }


    var afterSaveFuncAfterAdd = function(rowId, response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        $(this).jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, { Grupp: data.PrimaryKeyValues[0] });
        cancelEditing($grid);
     afterGridSaveFunc(rowId,response);
        jqXHRFromOnSuccess=null;
    };


    $.extend(true,
    $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {

        position: "beforeSelected",
        focusField: false,
        restoreAfterError: false,
        afterrestorefunc: function(rowId) {
            updateButtonState($grid, rowId);
            setFocusToGrid();
            lastSelectedRow = undefined;
        },
        aftersavefunc: function(rowId, response) {
            afterSaveFuncAfterAdd(rowId, response);
        },
        oneditfunc: function(rowId) {
            onInlineEdit(rowId);
            updateButtonState($grid, rowId);
        },
        keys: true,
        rowID: '_empty',
        useDefValues: true,
        extraparam: { _dokdata: getEevaFormData },
        errorfunc: errorfunc
    });
</script>
    <div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <table id="grid"></table>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I added afterComplete according to answer and verified that correct id is passed to `attr()`. Problem persists. In second form or inline edit wrong key is still passed to server.
I updated testcase below.

Comment: If I remind me correctly you use custom buttons of `formatter: "actions"`. In the case [the last changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/9d838631c6c1a3809b3e61483421a77ab1740e01) in free jqGrid could be interesting for you. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to change the rowid of the row after editing. You send the editing data to the server using `prmNames: { id: "_rowid", ...}` option. So `postdata._rowid` should contains the rowid of editing row. The response from the server after editing seems looks something like

```
{"PrimaryKeyValues":["1","change","004"],"Id":"1ä_63_68_61_6E_67_65ä004"}
```

where `Id` property contains **new rowid** after editing the row. In the case you can use `afterComplete` callback

```
afterComplete: function (jqXhr, postdata, $form, formOper) {
    if (formOper !== "add") {
        var json = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText),
            p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
            oldId = p.idPrefix + postdata._rowid,
            newId = p.idPrefix + json.Id,
            i;
        $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(oldId)).attr("id", newId);
        if (p.selrow === oldId) {
            p.selrow = newId;
            i = $.inArray(oldId, p.selarrrow);
            if (i >= 0) {
                p.selarrrow[i] = newId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should include such callback in the `editParams` which you use for the form editing:

```
var editParams =  {
    afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
        return EditAddForm_AfterSubmit(response, postdata);
    },
    afterComplete: function (jqXhr, postdata, $form, formOper) {
        if (formOper !== "add") {
            var json = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText),
                p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                oldId = p.idPrefix + postdata._rowid,
                newId = p.idPrefix + json.Id,
                i;
            $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(oldId)).attr("id", newId);
            if (p.selrow === oldId) {
                p.selrow = newId;
                i = $.inArray(oldId, p.selarrrow);
                if (i >= 0) {
                    p.selarrrow[i] = newId;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    url: 'http://example.com/Edit?_entity=Grnait',
    closeAfterEdit: true,
};
```

Comment: I tried it but problem persists. New json.Id is passed to attr() in afterComplete but on second edit old id is still passed to server. I updated question with changed testcase.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. Can this added to jqgrid source code also ? This code runs only after form editing. Why `if (formOper !== "add")` is used ?

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! In case of `formOper === "add"` the **new row** will be added with the id returned from `afterSubmit`. So nothing should be done. No `$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(oldId))` will exist and so on. I don't see that the case is common and so the main code of jqGrid should be changed. I can imagine that the rowid could be change if there are editable column with `key: true`, but it's not your case. The main design goal of id is the following: it should be set during creating of data item and should **never be changed**. It allows to use optimistic concurrency control for example.

Comment: This code is always called with `formOper`  value of `"edit"`. Add form parameters are specified is separate parameter in navGrid. editParams are not used for adding. So this check is unnessecary. Or is it possible to use common parameters for both add and edit forms ?

Comment: @Andrus: You can use different variation of the code. I share the code of Add/Edit in the most cases. The value of the 3-d item of array returned by `afterSubmit` will be used by jqGrid only in case of Add operation, Edit uses only the first Boolean element of the returned array. One can share the code for Add/Edit if one want. You should see what is better in your case. I shown just how the rowid can be changed after form editing.

Comment: Is it possible to specify common afterComplete and other properties for both Add and Edit forms without setting it separately for add and for edit. For inlineediting `$.extend(true,
    $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {` works

Comment: @Andrus: I recommend you to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). You can use `formEditing` option of jqGrid to specify any common form editing options for the grid and `inlineEditing` option for common inline editing options. To set defaults *for all grids on the page* you can use `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` for inline editing and `$.jgrid.edit` for form editing. I recommend you to use new `inlineEditing`, `formDeleting`, `formViewing`, `searching`, `formEditing`, `actionsNavOptions`, `navOptions` options of jqGrid.